# How to Generate All Possible CSS 2 Selector Combinations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-selectors

What would be the best way to generate all possible CSS 2 Selector Combinations for a DOM element in context with the current state of the `document`?

Eg:
    For the following MarkUp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li class="last-li">c</li> <!--ARGUMENT ELEMENT-->
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A JS/jQuery Method such that the `<!--ARGUMENT ELEMENT-->` in the above markup is given as an argument to the method it returns all possible CSS 2 Selector combinations for the Argument in form of an array. An optional parameter can be added to the method which will define the maximum depth of CSS 2 Selector Nesting. If this parameter is set to false it should return all possible combinations (Will be a performance hogger if set to false)

Example Output:

```
[
 ".last-li",
 "li.last-li",
 "ul .last-li",
 "ul li.last-li",
 "div ul .last-li",
 "div ul li.last-li",
 "#content ul .last-li",
 "#content ul li.last-li",
 "div#content ul .last-li",
 "div#content ul li.last-li",
 "body div ul li.last-li",
 "body div ul .last-li",
 "body #content ul li.last-li",
 "body div#content ul .last-li",
 "body div#content ul li.last-li",
]
```

Any pointers in this regard will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Throw in all the other selectors and even the most trivial documents will generate huge numbers of possible selectors. This can't be a useful exercise, surely?!

Comment: You mean CSS selector combinations. Anyway, what do you need them for? There are a **large number**, perhaps **hundreds**, of possible CSS selectors for that element alone, more than the ones in your example.

Comment: I presume you _do_ realize that even for a slightly larger html document, the total number of combinations is going to be really large!

Comment: @BoltClock: Exactly. I will correct the question.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: I understand that, that is the reason I mentioned of a 2nd argument which can cut down on the level of nesting. For most Practical purposes the levels of 3 should do fine.

Comment: @GeekTantra: For one level of nesting alone, I can think of at least 30 selectors that all match `.last-li`.

Comment: @BoltClock: That is true. With the increasing depth of the element in  the document the number of combinations keeps increasing. Any pointers on the logic front how this can be done?

Comment: What about something like `:root > :last-child :only-child:not(ul) :not(:nth-last-child(2n+1)) ~ li`?

Comment: @Gumbo: Let me edit the question with CSS 2 Selectors. :)

Comment: Can you tell us why? I'm curious because this list could be massive, `body .last-li` is also valid.

Comment: @BoltClock: I understand that. I Just reduced guess 150 odd to 30 by putting CSS 2. :)

Comment: @Gumbo do you think you can generate an infinite (possibly countable) set of selector for any element (using full CSS syntax) ? @GeekTantra I have a feeling you can generate an infinite amount using some of the pseudo classes.

Comment: @Raynos: I think each element will have a finite number of selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock you can chain `:not` infinitely. It's not a sensible selector but its a valid one.

Comment: @BoltClock: The number of selectors will be infinite but countable (May be exceeding range of most JS engines) as Raynos says if the depth of the document is considerable.

Comment: @Raynos: Oh, right, good point.

Comment: @GeekTantra: Well are you going to spend all the engine's available resources on calculating the selectors alone? *What for, anyway?*

Comment: @Raynos: Guess that is true for CSS 3 selectors.

Comment: @GeekTantra I can think of an infinite amount of selectors for the `<body>` in `<html><head /><body /></html>` ;) Depth of the document isn't really relevant.

Comment: @BoltClock: Of-course not. This might not be practical for n-levels on any browser but I was looking at how this can be put in to some logical code.

Comment: @GeekTantra I'll repeat what everyone else is saying. You need to give us the reason why you need this list so that we can limit the list to a sensible subset or suggest an alternative solution. Otherwise this will get nowhere

Comment: @Raynos: Basically, for a selected element I wanted to give the user an option to choose the CSS selector and define its properties. Of-course the options are rendered useless if they are infinite.

Comment: @Raynos: At least [combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators) will always reduce the number of matching elements. But any [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) can be used in an infinite manner like `:first-child:first-child:first-child` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's stick to a narrow class of selectors involving tag names, class names and IDs, nothing fancy like `E > F` or `E + F`. Let's also disallow combinations of class names (`.class1.class2.class3`), otherwise a single element with 10 class names would generate 4 million selectors alone.

Each of our full selectors consists of simple selectors separated by spaces. Every simple selector is a combination of `tag{0,1}id{0,1}class{0,n}` - i.e. each element has exactly one tag, at most one ID, and it can have an arbitrary number of class names. That gives us the upper limit of 2 * 2 * (n + 1) simple selectors for a single element.

Given a reference to a DOM element grab it's tag name, ID and class names. Calculate all possible simple selectors as described above. Lets call this set A1. Move one step up the hierarchy to it's parent, calculate all simple selectors for that parent element - that'll be the set A2. Continue until you reach the html element - the set Am. Now you'll have a list, consisting of m items, each item is a set of simple selectors.

Now pick some of these sets and find their cartesian product. Say, m = 5. How many sets can you pick? The set A1 is always present, but others are optional. For each one of them you either pick it or not. That's like binary numbers:

```
0000 // 0, A1
0001 // 1, A1 x A2
0010 // 2, A1 x A3
0011 // 3, A1 x A2 x A3
0100 // 4, A1 x A4
...
```

That means you'll have 2^(m-1) cartesian products. You can now convert them to strings. The last step is to remove duplicates, consider this example:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Our calculations will yield this list:

```
  span
  div span // inner div
  div span // outer div
  div div span
```

Those two divs yield duplicate selectors. Remove those and the job is done.
All the steps are very simple algorithmically. I'm sure you can figure them out, but if you get stuck somewhere or need further clarification feel free to ask me in the comments.

---

**UPDATE**

So, I decided to play with it a bit more and wrote the program, here's the list of selectors your example generates: http://pastie.org/1616164