# Puppeteer select link in nth child of table cell

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a function:

```
const tableData = await page.evaluate(() => {
 const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr td'))
 for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
 ...
 ...
  availableDates.push([i,dateString,day])
 }
 return availableDates
}
```

and this function cycles all cells of a table and I filter based on some conditions some dates out of there.

So far so good. The cells contain a href which I want to click. The array holds the number of the cell which I want to click on the first array item and so I have tried:

```
await page.focus('table tbody tr td:nth-child('+tableData[0][0]+') a' )
    await page.keyboard.type('\n');
```

but without luck. I get the following error message:

```
(node:81325) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: table tbody tr td:nth-child(109) a
.......
```

What must I change? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work because, let my explain why:

You have 2 tables.

- Table 1 has 3 tds.
- Table 2 has 2 tds.

Now, if you do `$('table td:nth-child(2)')` which will mean **Table 1**s 2nd td, also **Table 2**s 2nd td.

---

You can probably do 2 things,

1. While traversing the dom elements, add a data attribute to the elements and select it using that data attribute.

   ```
   const tableData = await page.evaluate(() => {
     const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr td'))
     for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
       // ...
       tds[i].setAttribute('data-td-index', i);
       // ...
       availableDates.push([i, dateString, day])
     }
     return availableDates;
   }
   ```

   Then, use that data attribute.

   ```
   await page.focus('table tbody tr td[data-td-index='+tableData[0][0]+'] a' )
   ```
2. Using one of the solutions here [get thee unique selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706837/get-unique-selector-of-element-in-jquery) of the DOM element and save it in the 
   `availableDates` i.e `availableDates.push(i, uniqPath, dateString, day)`.
   Then use it like:

   ```
   await page.focus(`${tableData[0][0]} a`)
   ```

Comment: I like the idea of setting an attribute, but when calling the page.focus it throws this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'table tbody tr td:[data-td-index=29] a' is not a valid selector.

Comment: aha! sorry there shouldn't be any colon `:` between `td` and `[`. Edited the post

Answer (score 1):

That's not how CSS selectors work. You can't do `td:nth-child(109)` and expect elements in different table rows to be picked. I'd try using `.click()`, either via `page.click` or `page.evaluate(() => element.click);`

Typing `\n` seems like a wrong directior, explicitly calling click - that'd be my advice.

Api for `page.click`: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options

When it comes to actually finding the right cell, I'd go with helper array in a higher scope (closure), add everything there (single dimensional array) and then you can reference them via number, such as you tried with `nth-child` approach.